# Как составить запрос в Doctrine QB на выбоку максимального значения в группе?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

Нужно группировать по `od.name`. Чтобы в результатах остались записи с максимальным значением поля `od.price` по группе.

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder->select('od')
    ->from(OrderDetail::class, 'od')
    ->where('od.name LIKE :chars')
    ->groupBy('od.name')
    ->orderBy('od.name','DESC')
    ->setParameter('chars', '%' . $chars . '%')
    ->setMaxResults(20);

return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

пример таблицы:

```
|  id  |  name   |  price  |
|   1  |  prim1  |    100  |
|   2  |  prim1  |    250  |
|   3  |  prim1  |    300  |
|   4  |  prim2  |     90  |
|   5  |  prim2  |     80  |
```

ожидаемый результат:

```
|  id  |  name   |  price  |
|   3  |  prim1  |    300  |
|   4  |  prim2  |     90  |
```

Comment: `->select('od.name, max(price) as pmax')` ?

Comment: а `pmax` еще будет использоваться?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```
$queryBuilder->select( 'a' )
    ->from( OrderDetail::class, 'a')
    ->orderBy( 'a.name','DESC' )
    ->where('a.name LIKE :title')
    ->innerJoin( OrderDetail::class, 'b', 'WITH', 'a.price > b.price' )
    ->groupBy('a.name')
    ->setParameter('title', '%' . $chars . '%')
    ->setMaxResults(20);
```